# Else block not working

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Whenever I enter an invalid number (e.g. number too long, or a letter) for the denominator, I always get "NOtZero".  My If/Else statement logic is incorrect.  What is wrong and how can I solve this problem?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Enter Numerator");
   int numerator;
   bool IsNumeratorConverstionSucess=Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numerator);

    if (IsNumeratorConverstionSucess)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Denominator");
        int denominator;
        bool IsdenominatorConverstionSucess = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out denominator);
        if (IsdenominatorConverstionSucess && denominator != 0)
        {
            int result = numerator / denominator;
            Console.WriteLine("Result is = {0}", result);
        }
        else
        {
            if(denominator==0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NOtZero");
            }
            else
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Deominator Should Be A Valid Number Between {0} To {1} Range", Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Numerator Should Be A Valid Number Between {0} To {1} Range",Int32.MinValue,Int32.MaxValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's *really* unclear what you're trying to achieve. I assume English isn't your native language - which is fine of course, but does make it harder for us to help you. I suggest you ask a friend or colleague who has better command of English to help you explain what you're trying to do and what's going wrong.

Comment: ok ThankS For Suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting "NOtZero" when you enter an invalid denominator, is because `int.tryparse` sets it's out parameter to 0 when it fails.  So, your code is using the following workflow when you enter an `a` for the denominator value:

1. instantiate a variable called `denominator`
2. try to convert the user input to an integer, and return that to `denominator`
3. convert fails, so return `false`, set `denominator` set to 0

Comment: Thanks for Suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Johnie Karr is right, your logic fails because denominator will always be 0 if the parse had failed.

Another way to do this would be to move zero check logic inside of the success branch.

```
if (IsdenominatorConverstionSucess)
{
    if(denominator==0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NOtZero");
    }
    else
    {
        int result = numerator / denominator;
        Console.WriteLine("Result is = {0}", result);
    }

}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Denominator Should Be A Valid Number Between {0} To {1} Range", Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue);
}
```

Comment: Anatoly Sazanov very very  Thanks  Problem Solve i am Your fan